# Traverse tree to collect all children nodes, excluding unrelated branches

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, traversal

I have a list of child-parent tuples. I would like to traverse through the tree to collect all the children for input node.

```
in_list = [(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(6,5),(7,4),(8,4)]
```

Say now I would like to collect all children for node 2. That would be

```
out_list = [3,4,7,8]
```

Does this problem or its solution have any specific name? Just need to know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse these nodes in `in_list` like [**DFS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), You can try this:

```
def DFS(path, lst, father):
    for (a,b) in lst:
        if b == father:
            path.append(a)
            DFS(path, lst, a)
    return path

in_list = [(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(6,5),(7,4),(8,4)]
res = DFS([], in_list , 2)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
in_list = [(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(6,5),(7,4),(8,4)]
def paths(n, c = []):
   if not (t:=[a for a, b in in_list if b == n]):
      yield from (c + [n])
   else:
      yield from [j for k in t for j in paths(k, c+[n])]

print([*set(paths(2))][1:])
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 7, 8]
```